# How can i get it to show my image using the scikit image library. I have been getting errors

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xoeP.png)
this is the error that i have been getting
FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/home/jovyan/Downloads/filename.jpg'

i am trying to open and show an image using scikit image library but it hasnt been working

Comment: Does the file exist???

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of code, copy-paste the code into your post. [See here why.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace. Paraphrasing an error message is not useful.

Comment: yes the file exists

Answer (score 0):

I guess you made mistake.
do it this way.

```
r'/home/jovyan/Downloads/filename.jpg'
```

Put the character 'r' at the beginning of the root directory.

Comment: : No such file: '/home/jovyan/Downloads/filename.jpg'. gave me this error and much more aswell

Comment: @codeman I know, that's why I said to write the directory like the one that I did. I am still not sure you got my point. please check that out simply by checking tons of stack search engine results.